# Subtracting a set from a set of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let say that I have a set of set X = { {a,b}, {a,c}}  and I want to remove the element {a,b} from X. What is the proper way to write this subtraction operation.

X \ {a,b}

or

X \ {{a,b}}

I think that the first one is incorrect and that I should use the second one.  Is this correct? Or is there other way to write this?

Comment: Second way is correct.

Comment: Note that $\{a,b\}$ is actually NOT a subset of $X$, but $\{\{a,b\}\}$ is.

Comment: Ok. I have edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is right. It doesn't matter that the elements are sets -- if you want to remove the element $E$ from set $X$, you write $X\setminus\{E\}$, and if $E$ itself happens to be a set written with braces you get two pairs of braces.

One nitpick: $\{a,b\}$ is not a *subset* of $X$ (say, because $X$ does not have $a$ as an element) -- it is an *element* of $X$.

Comment: gah.  You beat me by 40 seconds! :D

Comment: @anorton: Possibly only because I submitted before adding the "subset" nitpick.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I will vote it as best answer in a few minutes since it is the first one that I saw. But I upvote both of you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The second one is correct.

Note that $\{a,b\}$ is **not** a subset of $S = \{\{a,b\},\{a,c\}\}$, but rather an **element** of $S$.

The set difference operator ($A\setminus B$) is defined between two **sets**, not a set and an element thereof.  Thus, you want to use $\{\{a,b\},\{a,c\}\} \setminus \{\{a,b\}\}$.